# Flutter setState of *multiple instances* of a Stateful Widget in a Page

Tags: flutter, widget, stateful, rebuild

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dicee'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DicePage> createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Die(DiePosition.Left),
          Die(DiePosition.Right),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum DiePosition {
  Right,
  Left,
}

class Die extends StatefulWidget {
  final DiePosition diePosition;
  Die(this.diePosition);

  @override
  State<Die> createState() => _DieState();
}

class _DieState extends State<Die> {
  Map<DiePosition, int> dieNumbers = {
    DiePosition.Left: 1,
    DiePosition.Right: 1
  }; //

  Random rd = Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        child: Image.asset(
          'images/dice${widget.diePosition == DiePosition.Left ? dieNumbers[DiePosition.Left] : dieNumbers[DiePosition.Right]}.png',
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setBothDiceState(rd);
          print(
              '${widget.diePosition.toString()} pressed! LB: ${dieNumbers[DiePosition.Left]} RB: ${dieNumbers[DiePosition.Right]}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void setBothDiceState(Random rd) {
    setState(() {
      dieNumbers[DiePosition.Left] = rd.nextInt(6) + 1; // 1...6
      dieNumbers[DiePosition.Right] = rd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }); // 1 - 6
  }

}
```

There are two Die instances in a row on the DicePage and I wish that whenever a press either of the dice, both update on screen.

However only the one I press updates on screen, in spite of both of the dieNumbers in the Map updating as expected.

Everything was working as expected until I tried to extract the Die class from the DicePage.
I can't figure out how to rebuild both instances on the DicePage.

Comment: I would appreciate any refactoring suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made minimum changes so it should work like you want

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dicee'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DicePage> createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Die(DiePosition.Left, setState),
          Die(DiePosition.Right, setState),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum DiePosition {
  Right,
  Left,
}

class Die extends StatefulWidget {
  final DiePosition diePosition;
  Function(VoidCallback) setParent;
  Die(this.diePosition, this.setParent);

  @override
  State<Die> createState() => _DieState();
}

class _DieState extends State<Die> {
  static Map<DiePosition, int> dieNumbers = {
    DiePosition.Left: 1,
    DiePosition.Right: 1
  }; //

  Random rd = Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        child: Image.asset(
          'images/dice${widget.diePosition == DiePosition.Left ? dieNumbers[DiePosition.Left] : dieNumbers[DiePosition.Right]}.png',
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setBothDiceState(rd);
          print(
              '${widget.diePosition.toString()} pressed! LB: ${dieNumbers[DiePosition.Left]} RB: ${dieNumbers[DiePosition.Right]}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void setBothDiceState(Random rd) {
    widget.setParent(() {
      dieNumbers[DiePosition.Left] = rd.nextInt(6) + 1; // 1...6
      dieNumbers[DiePosition.Right] = rd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }); // 1 - 6
  }

}
```

So what I did is that each Die gets the function passed that calls setState for the parent. This way calling that will update both. Furthermore it was necessary to make the `dieNumbers` static because otherwise each Die has their own map

Comment: WOW! You made it look easy! I still need to get used with states. Thank you a lot, mr. Ivo!